# Probability that X = 1 where X is minimum of two random variables when a dice is roled.

Tags: probability, random-variables, dice

A fair die is rolled twice. Let **X1** and **X2**  denote the outcomes, and define random variable  **X** to be the minimum of **X1** and **X2**.
Then, what is the probability that **X = 1** and Also, what is **E(X)**

I thought , since its minimum of **X1** and **X2**, it can be either **X1** is 1 or **X2** is 1, so, answer is **2/36**. but, looks like i am wrong. please help

Comment: Awesome! Now we understand where you are having trouble, we can help :)

Comment: @TonyHellmuth, thanks. please help me with this. Also, if you have any reference material, please give me links to it

Comment: Consider that $X_1$ and $X_2$ can take up to 6 values each. So how many ways can either of them be $1$?

Comment: two ways right..either X1 can be 1 or X2 can be 1

Comment: Sorry I think I may not have made myself clear. When $X_1=1$ and $X_2=6$ what is $X$? What about when  $X_1=1$ and $X_2=5$ what is $X$

Comment: X is 1, oh, so..i have to see when and all X will be 1 , so, answer is 11/36?, since 1,1 is repeated twice?

Comment: Yep! Okay now just to give you some background, we are dealing with what is called "ordered statistics" of discrete random variables. In this case $X_1$ and $X_2$ are discrete uniform random variables. Here is a link that should help :) http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~mbaiocch/Order%20statistics.pdf

Comment: please add it as an answer, it would seriously help other's who have the same doubt right. And also, how would i calculate E(x)?

Comment: Given what we have discussed so far, would you like to attempt it first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78376/discussion-between-ben-max-and-tony-hellmuth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(X=1)=P(X_1=1\vee X_2=1)=P(X_1=1)+P(X_2=1)-P(X_1=1\cap X_2=1)=$$$$P(X_1=1)+P(X_2=1)-P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1)=\frac16+\frac16-\frac16\frac16$$

Or:

$$P(X=1)=1-P(X>1)=1-P(X_1>1\wedge X_2>1)=$$$$1-P(X_1>1)P(X_2>1)=1-\frac56\frac56$$

---

Hint for expectation.

If $X$ is a random variable taking values in $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ then:$$\mathbf EX=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(X\geq k)$$